# How do I create a div button without javascript?

Tags: css, vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I have a button image made out of divs. When I click this I want to post back and redirect. 
What is the best way to do this and can it be done without using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to trigger the post back from the 'div' click then you'll need to use JavaScript. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342032/raise-postback-event-from-div-tag) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Use an input element of type 'submit'...

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Then redirect on the server (it will vary depending on the programming language being used)

Comment: How? the html is currently?                                      <div id="btnRetrieve2" runat="server" class="btnStyleGen" onclick="PanelClick()">
                <span class="left"></span><div><asp:label runat="server" ID="Label1"></asp:label></div>    
                <span class="right3"></span>    
                <div class="clear"></div>                    
            </div>