# Is it possible to apply an onclick() event to a span tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net

To make sure that an event handler is written properly, I generally have Visual Studio generate the event for me.  However, I can't find a way to do this with a div and I've tried typing it out myself to no avail.  Is this even possible without writing any javascript? (I saw similar questions, but couldn't seem to find anything that fit my needs).

Edit:  Basically I have a logoff div disguised to the user as a button.  When they click it, I want the following to happen:

```
 protected void LogOff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session.Abandon();

        //This will clear the authentication cookie
        HttpCookie myHttpCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
        myHttpCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(myHttpCookie);

        //This will clear the session cookie (not required for my application but applying to be safe)
        HttpCookie myHttpCookie2 = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
        myHttpCookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(myHttpCookie2);

        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    }
```

Here's where I call this event:

```
 <a href="Log_In.aspx"><span class="MenuItem" runat="server" onclick="LogOff_Click">Log Off</span></a>
```

Comment: Please post your event handler and relevant markup.

Comment: You want to cause a Postback to occur so that you can run a server-side function, is this correct?  [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342032/raise-postback-event-from-div-tag) might help with that.

Comment: Well, the `onclick` on the client side is still going to execute JavaScript (either inline or a function call).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `LogOff_Click` is fine.  However, you need to modify your markup.  Apply the `onserverclick` event to the `<a>` tag instead of `<span>`.  In your case, try the following:

```
 <a href="Log_In.aspx" runat="server" onserverclick="LogOff_Click"><span class="MenuItem">Log Off</span></a>
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Description

The `div` element supports the javascript event `onclick` so you can do it.
You can check if a html element supports a given event by looking on [w3c shools tag definition](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp).

**It is not clear to me what you exactly mean. You can do many things using javascript on the client side. `onclick` is javascript but you can do things like redirects using the serverside (Postback on ASP.NET Webforms) too. Things you do with javascript are, without doing ajax, not noticeable by the server, cause javascript get handled by the browser.**

Check out my sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/gqadg/1/)

#### Sample for the `<div>` tag

**Html**

```
<div onclick="alert('hello');">hello world</div>
```

#### More Information

- [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/gqadg/1/)
- [w3c shools tag definition](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp)

Comment: Thanks! Damn, very bad that i have reached the 200 points per day limit, but i like to help. Even if i cannot get more points using upvotes.

Comment: @DavidHoerster 1 minute too late, again ;) No problem. Thank You anyway.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the w3c source, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to stay in ASP.NET, you could use a `Panel` control and do something like this:

**Markup**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pan1">click here</asp:Panel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pan1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:alert('here');return false;");
    }
}
```

You're still writing JavaScript, but you're staying with the ASP.NET controls and the ASP.NET way of setting client-side events.

I actually prefer the method of dknaack and Silvertiger -- put the event in the client side code (preferably a javascript file instead of inline).

Answer (score 1):

Standard DOM and CSS will allow this

```
<div style="cursor:hand;" onclick="this.document.location.href ='http://www.google.com';">
    My content
</div>
```

should do the trick

Comment: +1 - prefer the client-side way of handling this over server-side...plus, not sure why you were downvoted, so I thought I'd even it out.

Comment: @David Hoerster it doesn't take much common sense to realise the answer has no relevance to the question at all. Well done!

Comment: How is it not relevant? you don't need C or ASP to implement html DOM/Javascript to complete the function without server side intervention.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you intend to do. When the onclick event is triggered, you would need a handler to be called, when the event is triggered. This is done via Javascript.

You can do a form submit in the JavaScript, or trigger an Ajax callback in the Javascript, to interact with your .NET application.

Answering the original question, onclick event can be triggered via `<div>` tag. Make sure you test against Internet Explorer 7/8 (compatibility mode) as not all events work in IE 7/8. It should be okay in Firefox, Chrome and IE9. Save this in a file and experiment.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function JSFn()
{
   //you can use the div ID if needed: var id = document.getElementById('div_id');
   alert("JSFn was called");
   //Can do form submit or Ajax callback to interact with .NET app

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<a id="anchor1" href="javascript:JSFn();">Make a clickable link here, you can use onclick and href='#'  </a>
</div>

<div id="div_id2" onclick="JSFn()">Just click here </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for doing a form submit, you would need to have the <div> enclosed within a <form> tag.