# execute serverside code on div click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

**ASPX CODE**

```
<div id="c" runat="server" onclick="loadContentFamily" onmousedown="loadContentFamily" rel="divUpdatePanel" >Family</div>
```

**ServerSide Code**

```
Public Sub loadContentFamily(ByVal PageName As String)
        MsgBox("")
        PageName = "Family"
        Dim _con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("LeaveDBConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Dim _da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT PageHeader,PageContent FROM PageKeeper WHERE PageName='" & PageName & "'", _con)
        Dim _table As New DataTable

        Try
            _con.Open()
            _da.Fill(_table)
            _con.Close()
            _con.Dispose()
            With _table.Rows(0)
                h4header.InnerText = .Item(0)
                divUpdatePanel.InnerHtml = .Item(1)
                Me.Title = .Item(0)
            End With

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            divUpdatePanel.InnerText = "No Data Found"
        Finally
            _con.Close()
            _con.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

**PROBLEM:**

When i click on the div it does not execute the ServerSide Code ...why??Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to raise a server event, not client event (and it looks like you want to do that asynchronously).

A quick and dirty way of accomplishing this is to use a hidden server button. The button can be located wherever desired (such as inside an `UpdatePanel`) and it allows proper usage of the ASP page lifecycle.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnPostback" style="display:none" onclick="serverEventHandler" />

<div onclick="document.getElementById('<%= btnPostback.ClientID %>').click()">Clickable DIV</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out this post [raise postback event from div tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342032/raise-postback-event-from-div-tag)

Yours would look something like

```
<div id="c" onclick="__doPostBack('loadContentFamily','')">
Family
</div>
```

**Edit:**

Try something like

```
<Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="c" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
```

It's explained better here [Partial postback with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965367/partial-postback-with-javascript)

Comment: can i add this to the triggers section of update panel??it does not show it the list of triggers.

Comment: this div is inside the update panel but clicking on it reloads the whole page.

Answer (score 3):

wrap your div inside a LinkButton control and call your loadContentFamily method on OnClick event of LinkButton. This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not using the UpdatePanel control, but jQuery. You can find an example [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/karan/archive/2010/09/12/calling-server-side-method-using-jquery-ajax.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Other alternative is to call a Javascript function and then make a  page method call . return data in form of xml & render in the div .