# Raise post back event on click of div tag just like Asp button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, dopostback

I want to raise post back event on click of div tag just we are doing with Asp button.

currently i am trying like this.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object Sender, EventArgs E)
 { 
  MyDiv.Attributes["onclick"] = 
              ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "MyDiv_Click");
}

public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
{
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventArgument))
            {
                if (eventArgument == "MyDiv_Click")
                {
                    MyDiv_Click();
                }
            }
        }

protected void MyDiv_Click()
{
// My Implementation
}
```

how to do that?

Comment: Sorry but this is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help].

Comment: i was trying with RaisePostBackEvent but it is not firing the event

Comment: @Srinivas look this link please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294626/execute-serverside-code-on-div-click

Comment: @NiMa Checked that link, but in my requirement i don't want to use another control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register `GetPostBackEventReference` in `Page_PreRender` and in `Page_Load` , check for 
`Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]`, if that is `MyDiv_Click` and page is posted back, then invoke `MyDiv_Click`.

**Full Code**

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    MyDiv.Attributes["onclick"] =
        ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "MyDiv_Click");
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack && Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] != null && Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == "MyDiv_Click")
    {
        MyDiv_Click();
    }
}
```

Screenshot -

[image]