# How to make an HTML row clickable while fetching data from the database (Using C#) in visual Studio

Tags: javascript, c#, html, visual-studio, html-table

I am creating a table header in HTML and for the table data, I am using a function which fetches data from the database and creates a table. Now, I want to make each of the rows of the table "clickable". I am not getting that how should I make the rows clickable. If someone can help me out it will of great help. HTML and C# code is provided.

HTML CODE:

`

```
        <!--Table head-->
        <thead class="mdb-color darken-3">
    <tr class="text-white">
     <th>#</th>
    <th>Equipment Name</th>
    <th>University Name</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Status</th>
        <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <!--Table head-->

        <!--Table body-->
             <tbody>


           <asp:PlaceHolder ID="DBPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>     


</tbody>`
```

C# CODE:

```
 public partial class List_of_Equipment{
```

: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabaseConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DBPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = getStudentData().ToString()});
        Console.WriteLine(getStudentData());
    }
    public string getStudentData()
    {
        string data = "";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select e.Ename as ename, u.Uname as uname, eu.Equantity as quantity, eu.Estatus as status from " +
                "Equipment e, University u, EquipmentUniversity eu where eu.Eid = e.Eid and eu.Uid = u.Uid", conn))
            {

                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sqlRdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    // table = new DataTable();  
                    // table.Load(reader);  
                    if (sqlRdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        int id = 1;
                        while (sqlRdr.Read())
                        {
                            string ename = sqlRdr.GetString(0);
                            string uname = sqlRdr.GetString(1);
                            int equantity = sqlRdr.GetInt32(2);
                            string estatus = sqlRdr.GetString(3);

                            data += "<tr><td>" + id + "</td><td>" + ename + "</td><td>" + uname + "</td><td>" + equantity + "</td>" + 
                                "</td><td>" + estatus + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<button class=\"btn btn-success btn-md\">Request</button><button class=\"btn btn-danger btn-md\">Hold</button> </td>" + "</td></tr>";
                            id = id + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What should happen when they click the row?

Comment: This should help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294626/execute-serverside-code-on-div-click

Comment: @ShaneRay by clicking on the row, I want to refer to a new HTML page showing the properties.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to go about making the row “clickable”.  One way is to simply modify the row tag to have an onclick handler.  Something like below

```
<tr onclick=“location.href=‘google.com’;”>
```

Replacing the “google.com” portion with the appropriate href of the details page you would like to navigate to.  You will also likely want to add a style to show the hand cursor... something like cursor: pointer

Comment: where will I be placing the above mentioned line of code (<tr onclick=“location.href=‘google.com’;”>) in my code?

Comment: Replace the tr here — data += “

Comment: Did this help?  If so, please consider marking this as the answer.